# mysql query To get the top two salary from each department

Tags: mysql

```
**Department table name** 
**following with fields name**

 id , empid ,salary ,departid ,status
```

how to get the top two highest salaries from each department with single query in mysql

Comment: it is a good question if you asked on right way..:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT emp1.departid , emp1.salary
FROM Department emp1
WHERE (
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(emp2.salary))
FROM Department emp2
WHERE emp2.salary > emp1.salary and emp1.departid  = emp2.departid ) in (0,1) group by emp1.departid , emp1.salary
```

I have tested this solution in sql server. But i think it will work in ms sql as well.

Comment: Allow me to explain! The magic is in the inner query:
the "emp1.departid  = emp2.departid" part limits comparison to be between same department salaries.
The "emp2.salary > emp1.salary" finds all salaries greater the current salary (in emp1). Counting those ones gives you a number! if this number is 9, it means our salary is top 10th, if the count is 0 it means our salary has none smaller than it, so it's the top 1st! 
Smart solution, Coder! Thanks

Comment: so, it gives you all salaries of the department that has only 1, or none salaries higher than them in the same department. (if 0, it's the highest, if 1 then the salary is the second highest)

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
SELECT id, empid, salary, departid, status
  FROM 
(
  SELECT id, empid, salary, departid, status, 
         @n := IF(@g = departid, @n + 1, 1) rownum,
         @g := departid
    FROM table1
   ORDER BY departid, salary DESC 
) q
 WHERE q.rownum <= 2
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00aa0e/5)** demo

What it does it generates in inner select a rank for each employee in each department based on the salary. Then in outer select it filters out all rows that have rank more than 2 (top two).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want. Please notice that this query is not tested, since I don't have access to a MySQL db atm.

```
SELECT 
    d1.id,
    d1.salary,
    d1.departid
FROM department d
WHERE
    d1.id IN
    (
        SELECT
            d2.id
        FROM department d2
        WHERE
            d2.departid = d1.departid
        ORDER BY salary DESC
        LIMIT 2

    )
```

It's probably not the most efficient query, but it does the job.

Comment: change top 2 to LIMIT 2, after `DESC`. TOP 2 is not mysql syntax

Comment: i don't think this works with mysql

Comment: @Justin Thanks, have been using MSSQL too much lately :)

Comment: IIRC SELECT TOP is a SQLServer dialect. MySQL uses LIMIT 0,2 instead.

Comment: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'